# Complex-valued first order quasilinear partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Let $U\in\tau_s(\mathbb{C})$ and $u\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a $C^\infty$ function with
\begin{equation}\label{eq-abc}
a(x,y,u)u_x+b(x,y,u)u_y=c(x,y,u),\qquad\qquad(1)
\end{equation}
where $a,b,c$ are complex-valued polynomial. Can we find the solution of the above equation? If not how about the simple situation as
$$u u_x+u_y=0.\qquad\qquad\qquad(2)$$
Remark: It is clear that in the case of $a=1$, $b=i$, and $c=0$, the solution is the class of holomorphic functions. If we write $u=u^1+u^2i$, then the equation (1) will be the Cauchy-Riemann equation
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
u^1_x-u^2_y=0,\\
u^1_y+u^2_x=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
And the equation (2) will be
$$(u^1+u^2i)(u_x^1+u_x^2i)+(u_y^1+u_y^2i)=0,$$
i.e.
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u^1u_x^1-u^2u_x^2+u_y^1=0,
\\
u^2u_x^1+u^1u_x^2+u_y^2=0.
\end{cases}\qquad\qquad\qquad(3)
\end{equation}

Thanks to Matthew Cassell, equation (2) is called the complex standard complex inviscid Burgers equation. There is a paper which may be about it:

Richard Kenyon. Andrei Okounkov. "Limit shapes and the complex Burgers equation." Acta Math. 199 (2) 263 - 302, 2007. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11511-007-0021-0

I can't read it right now, since there are too many new concepts for me in the article.

Comment: The second equation can be handled with the help of the method of characteristics (cf. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). I guess it can be adapted to the complex case.

Comment: $x,y,t$ are real-valued however $u$ is complex valued, how to solve the equation $\frac{d x}{d t}=u$?

Comment: For Burgers equation $$uu_{x} + u_{y} = 0$$ the first characteristic is $$\frac{du}{dt} = 0 \implies u = C_{2}$$ and hence $$\frac{dx}{dt} = u \implies \frac{dx}{dt} = C_{2} \implies x = C_{2} t + C_{1} \implies x = u t + C_{1}$$

Comment: Is the method of characteristics still valid when $u$ is complex-valued?  The equation (2) in real case will be equations (3).

Comment: $u^1u_x^1 + u^1_y = u^2u_x^2 \implies (u^1)^2_x + u_y^1 = (u^2)^2_x \implies (u^2)^2 = (u^1)^2 + \int u_y^1 dx$. Substituting this in the next equation we get a integral-differential equation in only $u^2$

Comment: Inviscid Burgers' equation $u u_x+u_y=0$ can be solved by solving the algebraic equation

$$u(x,y)=f_1(x-y\cdot u(x,y))$$

with respect to $u(x,y)$.
$f_1(x)$ is an arbitrary function.

**Example:** $f_1(x)=x \implies u(x,y)=\frac{x}{y+1} $

Comment: $u(x,y)=f_1(x-y\cdot u(x,y))$ is not a solution in the complex case. For example, let $f(z)=iz$. Then it follows from $u(x,y)=ix-iy\cdot u(x,y)$ that $u(x,y)=\frac{ix}{1-iy}$. Then $u_x(x,y)=\frac{i}{1-iy}$ and $$u_y(x,y)=\frac{-(ix)(-i)}{(1-iy)^2}=-\frac{x}{(1-iy)^2}.$$ It implies that $$(uu_x+u_y)(x,y)=\frac{ix}{1-iy}\cdot\frac{i}{1-iy}+\frac{-x}{(1-iy)^2}=\frac{-2x}{(1-iy)^2}\not\equiv 0.$$

Comment: @DATO Your calculation is wrong.
With $f(z)=iz$ we get $u(x,y)=\frac{x}{y-i}$.

Verify PDE:

$u(x,y) \frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{(y-i)^2}$ and $\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=-\frac{x}{(y-i)^2}$

Hence the PDE is satisfied, the sum of both terms is $0$.

Comment: Try it with $f(z)=2 z+i z^2$, we get $u(x,y)=\frac{i \left(\pm\sqrt{4 i x y+4 y^2+4 y+1}-2 i x y-2 y-1\right)}{2 y^2}$.
This also is a valid solution of Burgers' equation.

Comment: @gpmath Yes, I am wrong, $1-iy$ should be $1+iy$ in my comment. Is there a proof of the method of characteristics is valid and that all the solutions satisfy $u=f(x-yu)$?

Comment: @gpmath If $f_1$ is real differentiable, then the solution is valid by the chain rule. The mean of your `arbitrary function' (or in most books in differential equations) means real differentiable, or partial differentiable?

Comment: Found yet another solution generator for Burgers' equation:

$$\left(f_{2}\left(u\right)-y\right)\cdot u+x=0$$

**Example**: $f_{2}(z)=\frac{1}{z^2} \implies u(x,y)=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^{2}+4 y}}{2 y}$

Comment: @gpmath How do you find them？

Comment: @gpmath It seems that these two solution generators locally coincide. The second generator is $$\left(-\frac{f_2}{id}\right)(u)=-\frac{f_2(u)}{u}=x-yu,$$ so $$f_1=\left(-\frac{f_2}{id}\right)^{-\circ},$$where $id:z\mapsto z$ is the identity map and $f^{-\circ}$ is the inverse map of $f$, i.e. $f^{-\circ}\circ f=f\circ f^{-\circ}=id$. Thence the solution induced by $f_1$ and $f_2$ coincide when $rank_\mathbb{R}[D(f_1)]=2$.